# Data model based on postage rates

Tags: sql, data-modeling

I have a situation where I need to create a data model for 3 different shipping classes and the price for each category: 1st class (most expensive), 2nd class (second most expensive), 3rd class (least expensive) all depend on the total cost of the order.  Each class of postage and its accompanying cost is different and based on the total order cost level (i.e. between two numbers 0-$10.00 and up).  I am thinking this involves modeling 4 different tables and linking them together.  Am I correct in my thinking about this or is there a simpler way to data model this?

How should I approach this?

Any help or directions to be pointed in is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have a class table:

```
class  description
1ST    1st Class
2ND    2nd Class
3RD    3rd Class
```

the attributes of which would be used in the order table:

```
order_no  class  value  etc
10000     2ND    13.00  ...
10010     3RD    57.00  ...
```

and a table to hold the fees:

```
class  from_value  fee
1ST     0.00       4.00
1ST    10.00       6.00
1ST    30.00       8.00
2ND     0.00       2.00
2ND    15.00       3.00
2ND    40.00       5.00
3RD     0.00       1.00
3RD    50.00       3.00
```

That should be it on first glance.

Comment: @Thorsten_Kettner How would these be linked together by PK and FK?   The Fee table confuses me in this regard.

Comment: There is an order 10000 with a value of 13.00 and 2nd class. Looking up the fee in the fees table shows that a fee of 2.00 applies for this order(2nd class from 0.00 to < 15.00). If it is a `to_value` in the fees table you are missing; this is implicitly given by the following record (and can easily be retrieved with SQL's `LEAD` function). You could also store it redundantly (with the risk of storing overlapping ranges or leaving gaps).

Comment: The fees table's PK is class + from_value. It has an FK on class to the classes table. The order table's PK is order_no and it also has a FK on class to the classes table. And well, the classes table's PK is class here obviously.

Comment: @Thorsten_Kettner So all other relationships are one to one except for from Class to Fees which is one to many?

Comment: I'd say: 1) One class can be used in many orders, but each order has exactly one class 1:n. 2) One class has several fee records, but each fee record belongs to one class 1:n. 3) One fee record can be related to many orders, but one order has exactly one fee 1:n.

Comment: @Thorsten_Kettner thanks for your help... So from fee to orders there is no foreign key just a relationship of 1:n from fee to orders?  That part is what is confusing me at this point.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Some relations in a database are simply not modeled with foreign keys.

Comment: @Thorsten_Kettner OK.... so would a line be drawn from fees to orders then in the data model?

Comment: I don't know. I rarely draw any and when I do that I do that for myself, so I draw the lines such that it is easy for me to understand the model. So I might for instance use a dotted line which would probably violate some standard notation.